# How to pass a list of inputs into a constructor in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a Python constructor

```
def foo(a, b, c):
     __def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

and I have a list of inputs

```
bar = [a, b, c]
```

Is there a way I can call the constructor with just a list of inputs? Eg,

```
foobar = foo(bar)
```

Or would I need to make an entire wrapper function, such as:

```
def fooWrapper(inputList):
   a = inputList[0]
   b = inputList[1]
   c = inputList[2]
   return foo(a, b, c)
```

Assuming I cannot change neither the constructor nor the way I receive the inputs (as a list), is there a more simple way to do this than creating a wrapper?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean something like `foo(*bar)`? Also note that your code is not valid Python

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work for the wrapper function:

```py
def f(a, b, c):
  return sum([a, b, c])

bar = [3, 2, 1]

total = f(*bar)

print(total)
```

Outputs `6`.

Since a constructor can not return a value, yes you need a wrapper.